# PHP Fatal Errors not in Error_Log, How to enable?

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

For some reason **fatal errors** do not appear in my server's **error_log** and I cannot seem to enable this level of logging. Standard *errors*, *php warnings* and *php notices* however are all logged.

Logfile: `/var/www/vhost/sitename/statistics/logs/error_log`

I have checked through my `php.ini`, `httpd.conf` and `.htaccess` and error reporting is set to `E_ALL`, but I must have missed something to enable fatal error logging.

The php config is:

```
display_errors  On  (Off)
display_startup_errors  On  (Off)
error_append_string no value    (no value)
error_log   no value    (no value)
error_prepend_string    no value    (no value)
error_reporting 2047
html_errors On  (Off)
ignore_repeated_errors  Off
log_errors  On  (On)
log_errors_max_len  1024
track_errors    Off
xmlrpc_error_number 0   (0)
xmlrpc_errors   Off
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong with the setup please? There must be a reason for this problem with php fatal errors?

Comment: Yes, all other standard errors, php warnings and php notices are logged.

Comment: care to post your testing script?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in your script, or, if you want to suppress notices, use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: setting this right in the script is quite silly, as this line may be never executed due to fatal error. the setting name itself is right though

Comment: I have the error reporting set in htaccess and php, and tried E_ALL, but no fatal errors get logged.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next command

```
php -i | grep error
```

It will show info about your php configuration and you can check if it is correct.

Comment: I'll post my php config settings above, but I can't see what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem for a few years now.

The only way I can even work around it is to temporarily enable display_errors ;-/